# How to configure jboss rewrite valve settings

Tags: mod-rewrite, jboss, url-rewriting, struts2, tomcat-valve

I am developing a web app. using struts2 and jboss url rewrite valve as you see from the title. What i want to know is which are the neccessary jboss configuration files to configure rewrite valve settings?
Besides, I couldn't find any information in order to fix my non-english character problem while url rewriting. Some flags like [NE] doesn't help.

Let me clear the case for you;
There is a link on my jsp page, its value is: 
http://localhost:8080/struts2Sample/redirectLogin/text/blahblah

And in my rewrite.properties file I added this code;
RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} ^/redirectLogin/text/(.*) 
RewriteRule ^/redirectLogin/text/(.*) /redirectLogin.do?text=$1 [NE,PT,L]

If the 'text' variable include non-english characters like 'şçğüıö' instead of 'blahblah' then the action gets a differently encoded value of 'şçğüıö', I mean it gets a string like '%C4%5F%' or including some another wierd characters.

If you have any idea about how I can fix this issue with, say, a rewriteMap or another flag include a piece of perl code, or (*up to me it is more effective solution*) **configuring a charset or encoding in an xml file of jboss like server.xml etc.** I will be glad to hear that.

Thanks a lot,
Baris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used URLEncoder.encode or decode for UTF-8 in order to prevent character problems